# PHP Fatal error: Out of memory in Wordpress

Tags: php, memory

I'm running a WordPress site on **EC2 t2.medium** machine. 
I've increased the memory_limit in `php.ini` to 3GB which is reflecting in `phpinfo`,
but I keep on getting "Out of Memory" error in 1-2 day frequency.

[image]

error_log

[image]

Below is the screenshot of `top` command

[image]

How can I resolve this or at least find what's causing this out of memory? 
Stuck on this for 4 days. Any help will be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you also running MySQL on the machine? How much memory is that using? You can check memory usage with `top`.

Comment: @Rup, I've added the screenshot of top command as well, and yes I'm using MYSQL on the machine, how can I check the MYSQL memory?

Comment: That's the VIRT and RES columns. It looks like your MySQL has 2GB of memory allocated. (However most of it is in swap - I don't think you're meant to use swap heavily on EC2 instances?) And that's only 6% of the resident memory, but since things are in swap I guess that spikes from time to time.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's an easy way to work out why PHP is using that much memory and reduce it - I've never had to, sorry - or tune how much memory MySQL needs, but if you can't find ways to reduce that then it looks like the combined MySQL + PHP is now too much for this one instance then. You'll either have to find a way to reduce the memory requirements for MySQL or PHP, or get an instance with more memory, or split MySQL off onto a separate instance.

Comment: You could also use a MySQL profiler to see what the biggest queries you run are - if it doesn't give you memory usage for the queries then look for the ones that have the largest temporary collections, which is probably the ones with the largest table scans. If you can optimise those you can probably reduce the MySQL memory requirements.

Comment: Other questions about this also suggest caching or static file offloading plugins too, to reduce the amount of work that WordPress has to do in PHP and Apache. But it looks like you're running a WooCommerce store so I'm not sure how much difference that would make since there's going to have to be some interactivity with carts etc.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments @Rup, But what do you suggest? What should I do here? Either try to optimize MYSQL or increase the memory

Comment: I don't know, sorry. You can try increasing the memory to check that that solves the problem first - I think it's fairly easy to do, but you need to be careful to make sure you keep the same IP address for the instance if that's the public IP address for your site, and your hosting costs will go up temporarily (more if you've got a reserved instance for t2.medium that you'd no longer be using). If that's too much of a risk or a problem then you could make a new instance and separate the database onto that, leaving the original instance alone.

Comment: And then you can look at optimising the memory usage afterwards, once everything is running smoothly again. There's also no guarantee that you'd be able to save memory anyway. As long as the increased hosting costs are OK then more memory is going to be the safest option for now.

Comment: Huge thanks @Rup